# Get and set position dynamically

Tags: android, button, position, dynamically-generated

I'm creating N buttons in a **for** loop witch an `OnClickListener` each one. The user is able to click each button and set a number. After that, I want a `TextView` showing the number just over the button and in the middle of it.

[image: Example of what I want]

This is just what I want. The gray background is the button, and the number is the `TextView`.

The code I have right now:

```
        for (int toShow = 0; toShow < nShips; toShow++)
            {
                btn = new Button(this);
                btn.setBackgroundResource(shipDrawable.get(ima));
                btn.setLayoutParams(params);
                row[pos].addView(btn);
                btn.setId(shipId.get(ima));
                btn.setOnClickListener(listeners);
                if (row[pos].getChildCount() == 3) pos++;
                ima++;
            }
```

I tried using this inside the for loop:

```
float x = btn.getX(), y = btn.getY();
                TextView level = new TextView(this);
                level.setText("5");
                level.setX(x); level.setY(y);
```

But didn't work. What can I use to get what I want?

Comment: Why you are not using text in Button.setText() ?

Comment: cuz I just wanna show an image

Comment: Then you should use ImageButton

Comment: Ok, I'll use ImageButton but... what's the difference?

Comment: In the Button you can show text on a button , on ImageButton you can show image on a button along with all the functionality of button

Comment: I now understand you, sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KrLx_roller the much i got is that you want to place text on a button , you do not need to take a septate text view you can add the text like this

```
    Button textOne = new Button(this);

    textOne.setText("5");
    textOne.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img);
    textOne.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textOne.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: The problem is that I have many N buttons, each one with its specific text. I want that value to change when the user introduce another value in an EditText. Ho do I do that? I've tried to do it but the text only changes on the last button created.

Comment: if you want to change the text of button on click with edit text , can do it like  textOne.setText(edittext1.gettext().tostring()); of apply condition on basis of the value in edit text

Comment: I've just found a solution! b = (Button)findViewById(id); 
                b.setText(String.valueOf(elegidos));

Answer (score 2):

If  you want to show Image on b button you should use ImageButton for this. Difference between button and image button is In the Button you can show text on a button , on ImageButton you can show image on a button along with all the functionality of button

Comment: Thanks but that's not my problem... I was just answering your question: Why you are not using text in Button.setText()?